# how to get web element in AppiumDriver from a hybird app?

Tags: cordova, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate a Cordova build hybird app using appium and selenium.

However, I am unable to get any element using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("xxx"));
```

when I do a pageSource dump using

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

    System.out.print("*************dumping: ***********\n"+pageSource+"\n\n\n");
```

I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><hierarchy rotation="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.alarmforce.connect.client.keypad" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1024,552]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.alarmforce.connect.client.keypad" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1024,552]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.alarmforce.connect.client.keypad" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,25][1024,552]" resource-id="android:id/content" instance="1"><android.webkit.WebView index="0" text="" class="android.webkit.WebView" package="com.alarmforce.connect.client.keypad" content-desc="Web View" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,25][1024,552]" resource-id="" instance="0"/></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout></hierarchy>
```

How do I make it show up in the HTML format like what was showing in chrome://inspect when I connected the device?

I tried:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
```

in MainActivity.java

I also tried:

```
driver.context("web_view");
```

the capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","xxxxxxx");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: try and get the list of the contexts and then switch to webview using :
`Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles(); // you can read the names of contexts hereby
driver.context(<webview name>);// set context to WEBVIEW`

Comment: thanks nullpointer for the quick response!   when I did:     `Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
  for (String contextName : contextNames) {
   System.out.println(contextNames); 
  } `                     I get     `[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.xxxxx.connect.client.keypad]
[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.xxxxx.connect.client.keypad]`

Comment: Ideally `driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.xxxxx.connect.client.keypad")` shall help you switch the context then

Comment: thanks!! it worked! ... on the virtual device, however I am still getting no such element error on the real device, I am lost..

Comment: could you edit the question and paste the error faced on the real devices

Comment: hi nullpointer, it is working now on devices as well, didnt really change anything... it might be the device or machine that were lagging few moment ago, it should be fine after I add in some WebDriverWait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to switch the context using appium is :

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
String setContext = contextNames.toArray()[1].toString(); //generally your WEBVIEW context if available
driver.context(setContext);// set context to the webview name in string format
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nullpointer, the problem is solved!!! for anyone that come across this issue, try this:

```
    System.out.print("*************dumping source before setContext(unusable stuff): *************\n"+driver.getPageSource()+"\n\n\n"); 


    Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    String setContext = contextNames.toArray()[1].toString(); //generally your WEBVIEW context if available
    driver.context(setContext);// set context to the webview name in string format

    System.out.print("*************dumping source after setContext(useful stuff): *************\n"+driver.getPageSource()+"\n\n\n");
```